# How to test a task with the Task Scheduler on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

Other than scheduling the time for execution to be in the near future, is there a way in the Windows 7 Task Scheduler to force a future task to execute now for the purpose of testing and observing it to ensure it works as desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the task in Task Scheduler and hit *Run* toward the bottom of list of actions on the right pane.

If *Run*, doesn't appear, go to the *Settings* tab of the task's properties and check the box that enables *run on demand*.

Answer (score 2):

In task scheduler, right click on the task in the upper pane and choose "run"
[image]

Frequently task status is frozen (showing "Running", although it is finished). Hit 'F5' to refresh tasks display.